# PnPjs: Filtering SharePoint document library by file name results in errors

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, spfx, pnp-js

I am working on a new web part to display a list of files in a SharePoint document library called `Medicine files`. I want users to be able to filter the files based on different columns, including file names. I am using PnPjs to search for files by name, and it works perfectly for other columns, but not for the file name. Here's my current code:

```js
 await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Medicine files").items.filter("FileLeafRef eq 'test.pdf'").expand("File").orderBy("Created", asc)();
```

When I use the `Name` column, I get the following error:

> Column 'Name' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

And when I use the `FileLeafRef` property, I get this error:

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.

I have tried different column names, such as `Name`, `DisplayName`, `FileLeafRef`, `LinkFilenameNoMenu`, `LinkFilename`, and `BaseName` without success. I have also checked the column name in the column settings, and it is defined as `Name`.

Any suggestions to help me resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the Graph SDK?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Medicine files").items.filter("FileLeafRef eq 'test.pdf'").expand("File").orderBy("Created", asc).getAll();
```

refer [pnp.github.io](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/) for details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34638979)